# Is it possible to figure out which package/script takes most of the startup time?

Tags: emacsclient, microsoft-windows, server, use-package

I used to run Emacs on Linux using Emacsclient, it is really easy and great experience:

```
emacs --daemon
emacsclient
```

When I work on a Windows machine, Emacs starts very slow. It seems there's no default support for emacsclient. So I decide to use the `use-package` package to reduce Emacs startup time. Since there're several packages, I'd like to know which cost the most startup time, and load it with `use-package`.

If I am not in the right direction, please correct me.

Comment: Which Windows package are you using? In the one I'm using there's a `emacsclient.exe`.

Comment: @legends2k I'm using emacs form `Chocolatey`, a `apt-get` like package management tool for Windows. I use it to install many opensource or free software. There's a `emacsclient.exe` too. How do you use it? Emacs doesn't support `daemon` on Windows.

Comment: Related questions have already been discussed at length: [What can I do to speed up my start-up?](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2286/what-can-i-do-to-speed-up-my-start-up), [How can I troubleshoot a very slow Emacs?](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/5359/how-can-i-troubleshoot-a-very-slow-emacs/5438#5438).

Answer (score 6):

Since you said you are already using `use-package`, you can turn on its own verbose option that reports how long each package takes to load.

Use `customize-option use-package-verbose` or put this in your init file:

```
(setq use-package-verbose t)
```

Then restart Emacs and check your `*Messages*` buffer. The output will look something like:

```
Loading package dash...done (0.015s)
Loading package ido...done (0.109s)
Loading package company...done (0.125s)
Loading package elisp-slime-nav...done (0.047s)
Loading package smart-mode-line...done (0.046s)
```

By default times are reported that are longer than 0.01 seconds. You can change this threshold too, see `use-package-minimum-reported-time`.

Answer (score 1):

This is based on Emacs 24.4.1 (KAEL) on Windows 7 from the [emacs-w64 project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/emacsbinw64), but should work on other releases of the same major version.
Add this to your `.emacs`:

```
(load "server")
(unless (server-running-p) (server-start))
```

which will run the server if it's not running; taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7131683/183120). If you're using cygwin/msys/msys2 then you could add this to your `.bashrc`:

```
edit_file() {
        emacsclient -nqa "runemacs.exe" $1 &
}

alias edit=edit_file
```

or do the equivalent in a batch script for `cmd`. Now all you've to do is

```
edit 1.txt   # will start the server, if it's not running
edit 2.txt   # will send a request to the server to open this file
```

The explanation part is that `emacsclient` would run `runemacs.exe` if a server is not running; `-q` would be to silence it's success message. `-n` is to not wait for server to return; if not for `-n`, [you should clean up](http://wikemacs.org/index.php/Emacs_server#Finishing_Up) the buffer using `server-edit` and not the usual `kill-buffer`.

One additional point is that, if you want to use `emacsclient.exe` from GUI instead of CLI/TUI then use `emacsclientw.exe`.

Comment: Error: file name or argument required. (I downloaded Emacs-w64 from your list, the same error occured.) (Thank you.)

Comment: What shell did you try it on, bash or cmd? Also what command gave you that error?

Comment: I run it with the native Windows `PowerShell`, and `bash`, both failed with the same error: `file name or argument required.`

Comment: Try this `emacsclient -nqa "runemacs.exe" <some_file> &` on bash, is it working?

Comment: This post does not answer OP's stated question about startup time.  If the OP can post a separate question on emacsclient for Windows, this answer would make more sense there.

Comment: @Dan Perhaps, but start up is made faster by running Emacs as a server and calling subsequent edits from the client. This is one possible solution, no?

Comment: Right, but OP seems to be aware of emacsclient conceptually (it's not clear if he found a way to get it on Windows).  I'm not taking issue with the content of your answer; I'm merely pointing out that the answer is a mismatch for the question as currently stated (figure out what takes so long at startup).